# Processbuilder without redirecting StdOut

Tags: java, stdout, processbuilder

Is it possible to redirect the output stream back into a process, or not redirect it at all?

The backstory:
I am trying to launch an executable using processbuilder. 
(Source dedicated server / srcds.exe to be exact)

As a result of launching it with the processbuilder, the console window of this executable remains empty. A few seconds after launch, the executable crashes with the error "CTextConsoleWin32::GetLine: !GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents" because its console is empty.

Comment: Strange. Redirecting `StdOut` is fine for me. For me your error occurs only, when attempting to redirect `StdIn`. My current Workaround is using `RCON` instead of `StdIn`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're talking about making the launched process' stdout go to the current process' stdout. If you're using JDK7, that's as simple as:

```
.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)
```

**Update:** (too much for a comment) I think you're confused. When you launch a process from a terminal, the process becomes a child of that terminal process, and the stdout is sent to that terminal. When you launch a process from Java, then the process is a child of the Java process, and its stdout goes to Java.

In the first case, there's a terminal showing stdout because you launched it from a terminal yourself, and that's what terminals do with stdout. When launching from Java, however, there wouldn't be a terminal window unless something in the process you launched opened a terminal, and stdout of the process you launched is handed back to you, the programmer, to do with as you will. The equivalent behavior to what you see when launching from a terminal is the `Redirect.INHERIT` that I already mentioned.

Your problem right now isn't Java. Your problem is not understanding how this "srcds.exe" expects stdin and stdout to be handled. Figure that out, and then come back and ask how to do that with Java.

I'm just guessing now, but you could try reading from the process' stdout and feeding it back into the stdin. Maybe that's what it's expecting? That sounds crazy, though.

Comment: That didn't work. It now does the exact same thing as just reading the Inputstream and printing it. What I need is to have it NOT read the output, so that the subprocess doesn't get its output "stolen".

Comment: Then please clarify what you're trying to achieve. Not reading the output will eventually cause your spawned process freeze up. That's not what you're looking for. You *have to* read the process' output and do something with it.

Comment: The console window of the application I am launching normally gets stuff printed to it. By launching it with the processbuilder, the output goes to my java instead of that console window. Because this console window remains empty, the application crashes, since it is expecting lines in there. What I want to do, is have the lines still appear in the console window of the sub-process so that it doesn't crash.

Comment: The thing is that srcds.exe launches its own terminal. Launching it with java causes all contents normally going into that terminal to go into the java (the terminal still appears, but remains empty), and when it tries to read its own terminal, it crashes.
The key is to launch the process without redirecting the Stdout.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the output like this

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(args);
Process p = pb.start(); 

//below code gets the output from the process
InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
InputStreamReader inread = new InputStreamReader(buf);
BufferedReader bufferedreader = new BufferedReader(inread);
String line;
while ((line = bufferedreader.readLine()) != null) {
    *do something / collect output*
}
```

Comment: Please note that API documentation discourages buffering in this case. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream()

Comment: The code you just gave me is exactly the code which is creating the problem. It is not the answer to my question.

Comment: @vizier: your link is slightly broken - it doesn't jump to `getInputStream()`.  However, the discussion of buffering in the `getInputStream()` documentation says "Implementation note: It **is** a good idea for the input stream to be buffered."    Perhaps you wanted to direct our attention to the opening (class level) documentation that says: "Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, **failure to promptly write** the input stream **or read** the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, and even deadlock." ?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this for a while, but the simplest i guess you could do is by transferring the streams yourself, using some kind of StreamTransfer class, you can say which `InputStream` gets written to which `OutputStream` in separate threads to avoid deadlocks. 
In this example, i execute `ls` then `cat` and manually wire the `stdout` of `ls` into the `stdin` of `cat`, and then `cat`'s `stdout` to `System.out` to print the final result :

```java
public class TestRedirectingStreams {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService threads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10); 
        Process echo = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls"),
                cat = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cat");
        threads.submit(StreamTransfer.transfer(echo.getInputStream(), cat.getOutputStream()));
        threads.submit(StreamTransfer.transfer(cat.getInputStream(), System.out));
        threads.shutdown();
    }
}

class StreamTransfer implements Callable<Void> {
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
    private InputStream in;
    private OutputStream out;

    public static StreamTransfer transfer(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        return new StreamTransfer(in, out);
    }

    private StreamTransfer(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
        this.in = in;
        this.out = out;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception { // write to streams when thread executes
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1) 
            out.write(buffer, 0, read);
        in.close();
        out.close();
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you want to use ProcessBuilder instead the example stays the same, since `ProcessBuilder.start()` returns the process you can still retrieve the desired streams and transfer accordingly.