# Running shell command from Spring WebApp

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, process, mysql

I want to invoke mysqldump from a Spring based webapp and write the output to a file. I want to be able to provide a download link to the user to the file created on the server.

I tried running the following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> <db_name> >" + fileName);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mysqldump -u <username> -p<password> db_name >" + fileName);
```

I tried the following values of fileName.

```
fileName = "mysql.sql";
fileName = "/tmp/mysql.sql";
fileName = servletContext.getRealPath("") + "/mysql.sql";
```

But the command is not successful. process.exitValue() returns an error code of 2 or 6.

```
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/mysqldump", " -u ", "<username>", " -p<password>", "<db_name>", " > ", fileName);
  pb.redirectErrorStream(true); // equivalent of 2>&1
  Process p = pb.start();
  p.waitFor();
```

This does not help as well.

Can someone tell me what is the best way to run such a command from the webapp? Where should the output file be created?
What is wrong with the commands above?

I need to be able to run this on different systems (Linux, Windows). The webapp runs on either system. I can abstract out the mysqldump path in a properties file if the need arises. But how do I make this work?

Comment: I guess the problem is with output redirection as running a command like "ls" returns an exit code of 0 but the output does not go anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably not a very good idea.  The servlet probably needs a very permissive security environment for this to work at all.  If you do a search you will find lots of people having problems with this.

Even if it works the runtime exec might block for some reason and the servlet would timeout, I don't know the ramifications of that, but they don't sound good to me.

We had a similar problem where I worked a couple of years ago and wrote a simple multithreaded server that would queue up requests, and run them when it got a chance and handled things like hangs, crashes and restarts.  It ran as a jsvc daemon.  The servlet sent it a message over a socket.

Comment: For a low load server can this be a big problem? I have everything in a XAMPP like setup on Windows so I can be sure of the path and all.

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/10791175/161628

Comment: The reason for the separate server is that these kind of commands can take a very long time to complete, possibly blocking or hanging.  Also they can crash leaving the servlet orphaned.  A server that simply picks up the command, queues it and lets you poll its state is much more web friendly.  Note that as the database gets bigger the time taken will increase, so you need to set your timeouts high. The other advantage of the separate server is that it can be called remotely if its port is open or from a non-java program.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I will consider doing this moving forward. For now this seems to work fine to demonstrate a feature.